# Use MSAL Auth token to consume Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-msal

I have an ASP.Net Web API 2 on which I implemented the following security:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet

It worked, I can't access the controllers except if I remove the [Authorize] attribute.

Now, I have a logged in user in a Xamarin app. The user is logged in via MSAL authentication which works fine too.
Very basic implementation :

```
var authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.ClientScope);
var token = authenticationResult.Token;
```

Now, I want to access the web API by giving the MSAL authentication token in the DefaultRequestHeaders with something like this :

```
this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Is there anyway this is possible ? How can I use this token to make my user consume my web API ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tutorial [Help protect a web API by using bearer tokens from Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet) you mentioned targets on AD v1.0 and you need to register your apps on Azure Portal. While [MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) targets on AD v2.0 and you need to register your app at [apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), and you need to use the middleware in your Web API 2 as follows:

```html
var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudience = clientId,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
};

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AccessTokenFormat = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"))
});
```

For more details, you could refer to [active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api).

Additionally, you could refer to [AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet) for code samples about the web api backend and the mobile client via MSAL accessing the web api backend.

**Update:**

- I downloaded the code sample [AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet)
- Follow [How to register an app with the v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration) for registering my app for v2.0 as follows:

  [image]
- Copy the **Application Id** from the above screenshot and update it to **TodoListClient** and **TodoListService** project as follows:

  [image]
- Launch **TodoListService** first, then you could debug **TodoListService** as follows:

  [image]

Also, you could copy the **Token** and leverage postman to simulate the request as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did use the sample project as a guide to implement the way you described.
I'll mark your answer as soon as I get another message than "{"$id":"1","Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}".

Thanks !

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete update !
I'm currently trying to get this working on my project now that it worked on the sample.

Comment: Thank you for your time.
I'm facing a problem where I don't hit my controllers and just get 401 errors instantly when trying to contact my API.
Any insight about this ?
Thank you again.
EDIT : Posted another question. Not sure both are related though
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516351/cant-connect-to-https-on-web-api-from-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: As I known, the api side would validate the audience (clientId) from the bearer token sent by the client, you could use https://jwt.io/ to decode the token and check with it. Since the core code is provided by the code sample and it could work as expected, for you project you could open a new question and provide your code snippet or sample project for reproducing this issue if possible.

Comment: I would check with your new question.

Comment: I've tried to create a new app, but it seems like the API has changed from the alpha to the preview versions...for instance, you can't pass the client id as a scope (what should I pass here?)

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Anyone knows if there's a way of getting the user name filled without having to implement the OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.OnValidateIdentity method? Currently, I'm using the event to fill the name claim of the ticket's identity...

Comment: I'm not able to find the class OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider